# jQuery UI Slider jumps weirdly when pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, css

I'm trying to simulate the iPhone's lock screen and the slider on the front is working mostly but when I click it it jumps forward weirdly. Also if I drag it from the right side it does the same thing but then it stops going and I actually stop dragging the slider and it's really annoying. I have an example of what's goin on here:
[Slider Test](http://cydia.stumpyinc.com/theme/magic/slider_test)
I've looked a lot of places and similar questions, but the answers were sadly unhelpful for me, one of those being setting the `margin-left:-35px;`. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks good for me in Firefox, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using an old version of jQuery, which is what I was using, but now I updated it on the live link, so if you visit it again you'll see what I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

It works lika a charm in latest Chrome. The weird behavior of jQuery scripts is usually caused by a **relatively slow PC or web browser**. 
What is your PC's configuration and which browser are you using?

**Update**
I would definitely remove arrow image and instead use that image as an background of the link (id="unlock-handle"). This fixes "drag and drop" issue in Chrome.

Comment: I was using an old version of jQuery and I'm trying to use a new one and forgot to update in the live site, if you click on the link again you'll see what I mean. I'm on a 64 bit brand new Windows 7 with a fresh install of Chrome, Firefox, and IE so I'm sure it isn't the computer/browser